# Joomla 2.5.17 Why cannot I see article editor?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have upgraded my Joomla site from 2.5.7 to 2.5.17. Then I installed [Attachments](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/3115) package.

When I click article manager or category manager in order to edit an article or category, I see a page with no textarea, no buttons, no menus[image: Joomla 2.5 error].

All the page content is this.

- I have tried to install new text editors: nothing changes.
- I have tried to select "No editor" for text editing: nothing changes.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: does it work when "Attachments package" is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these different steps to solve your issue:

1) First, check to see if the editor plugin is enabled:
Tools -> Plugin Manager. Locate your Editor and ensure it's enabled.
Also check Global Config and make sure default editor is set.

You could also try disabling the package you installed and see if it works afterwards. If not try to disable all the editors only leaving the default of Joomla and check again.

2) Change back to one of Joomla's installed templates and see if the problem remains.
If not, then it is a problem with your new template. There is a possibility of javascript problems.

Sometimes enabling the system plugin 'System - Mootools Upgrade' will help.

Otherwise check with your template provider for possible help.

3) Also turn php error reporting on as it may be this problem:

http://whatisgon.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/fixing-call-to-undefined-method-stdclassondisplay-error-in-joomla/

4) Lastly, I like to replace Joomla!'s editor with the JCE editor which has solved many issues like these before.
http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/

Comment: After re-installing the template the problem has gone away. According to error.log it says something wrong in com_content.

Answer (score 0):

You get a page like that when you have a fatal error. You can try disabling the attachments plugin and see if it solves the issue. If not, turn error reporting to maximum or development and see what messages you get.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled  **PLG_EDITORS-XTD_TOOLTIPS** plugin and it my problem solved.